# How to fix a collet chuck on a router

Tags: router, router-bit

I have recently been using my router a lot lately and have noticed that it's losing it's ability to grip the bit as during operation the bit will slowly change height to the point of almost falling out.

The router is fairly old so it might just be time to get a new router, but I was wondering if there were any suggestions on how to mitigate some of these issues or fix the collet so that I wouldn't have to look for another.

**Note:** I tried different bits thinking it could have just been the bit's metal slipping though they all had the same result.

Comment: I had this problem and you just need a new collet. Here was my question, which I think has a better answer than the one they have provided. http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/need-a-new-router-collet-or-bit

Comment: As @Ljk2000 says, get a new collet. That solved my previous puzzlement with this issue. Or a new router, they have improved over the years.